# Mysql like query skip special character

Tags: mysql

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE `English_name` LIKE '%FL7%'
```

Data:

```
FL-710 FLOWER
FL-711 FLOWER
FL-712 FLOWER
FL-713 FLOWER
FL-693 FLOWER
FL71 FLOWER
FL69 FLOWER
```

Output:

```
FL71 FLOWER
```

Expected Output:

```
FL-710 FLOWER
FL-711 FLOWER
FL-712 FLOWER
FL-713 FLOWER
FL71 FLOWER
```

Anyone can please tell me How can I achieve expected output. I don't want to scan special characters. when like query does not contain any special characters.

Comment: try `SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE `English_name` LIKE '%FL_7%'`

Comment: If you don't know what the format of data will be, use RLIKE, and if you know what is the format use: ```SELECT * FROM item WHERE English_name LIKE 'FL7% OR English_name LIKE 'FL_7%'```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE `English_name` RLIKE 'FL-?7'
```

`-?` means that `-` is optional.

**Update**

If you want to ignore any special characters in the column, you will need to remove them all from the value.

With MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.2 you could use REGEXP_REPLACE

```
SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(`English_name`, '\\W', '') RLIKE 'FL7'
```

`REGEXP_REPLACE(English_name, '\\W', '')` will only keep alpha-numeric caracters and the underscore (`_`).

If you want more controll, you will need to list all characters that have to be removed. For example: If you want to ignore "+", "-" and "." you would use

```
SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(`English_name`, '[-+.]', '') RLIKE 'FL7'
```

Note that some characters a very special (-: for regex and need to be escaped with a double backslash. If you don't know which characters those are, you can just escape them all.

And some caracters are even more special: To use a single queto in a singlequoted string you need to write it twice (`''`). To use a backslash you would write it four times (`\\\\`).

To ignore "+", "-", ".", "'", "?" and "\" you would need

```
SELECT *
FROM `item`
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(`English_name`, '[\\+\\-\\.\\''\\?\\\\]', '') RLIKE 'FL7'
```

And you will get a result like this:

```
FL-710 FL_OWER
F+L711 FLOWER
F\L.712 FLOWER
FL'713 FLOWER
FL71 FLOWER
```

[MariaDB 10.2 Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=91f58130b0a0643c111c08662018c45e)

But if you can't use `REGEXP_REPLACE` you would need to replace all characters one by one in a nested `REPACE` expression. To remove only "-" and "+" you would use

```
SELECT *
FROM `item`
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(English_name, '-', ''), '+', '') RLIKE 'FL7'
```

The more characters to remove, the more complex will be the expression. But you can write a function `remove_special_chars()` where you can use procedural programming to get more readable code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION remove_special_chars(str TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
BEGIN
    SET str = REPLACE(str, '-', '');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, '+', '');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, '*', '');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, '/', '');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, '.', '');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, '''', '');
    SET str = REPLACE(str, '\\', '');
    -- add more 
    RETURN str;
END
```

Then your query would be

```
SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE remove_special_chars(`English_name`) RLIKE 'FL7'
```

Comment: @shahrushabh And why not?

Comment: It is a user based search engine so I don't have an idea what they will type.

Comment: It is good idea if you tell me How to skip special character scanning.

Comment: Do you just want to ignore any "special character" anywhere?

Comment: Yes, Paul, I want same.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE `English_name` LIKE  'FL%'
```

This will work only if you all record start with "FL".